# Generate all posts in a single subdirectory

Tags: jekyll

I have a jekyll blog with some static files, my blog index is generating at `/blog` while all the posts are getting generated at `/`. How can I make it so that the posts get generated inside the `/blog` subdirectory?

Note that I am not looking to move the whole Jekyll installation to a subdirectory as I still want my sitemap, static pages etc to be at root.

I am not sure what code to provide but I am using [this](https://github.com/janczizikow/sleek) theme with gulp 4 and other upgraded packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `permalink` in `_config.yml` from

```
permalink: /:title/
```

to

```
permalink: /blog/:title/
```

You can read more about permalinks in [Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/).